# How to increase label padding in the nodes of a Vis.js network graph?

Tags: javascript, css, vis.js, vis.js-network

When creating network graphs with **[Vis.js](http://visjs.org)**, the nodes in the network are drawn with labels that - for my use case - don't have enough 'padding', i.e., there is not enough space between the node label text and the border of the node. The following pic illustrates it:

[image]

Considering the vast amount of config options already available in Vis.js, I thought increasing label padding would be simple, but for the life of me, can't figure out how to do it. Have gone through the official docs, and have searched through StackOverflow and Google, but found no hints. Feel like I'm missing something obvious - can anyone shed a light?...

Comment: does the answer by Per Hornshøj-Schierbeck work for you? If so, please mark it accepted (it worked for me nicely)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it - at least it's working for vis@4.20.1 which i installed with npm. They use margin to modify the space between the border and the label text.

The options object you pass in, it needs a `margin` property on the `nodes` property like this:

```
const options = {
  nodes: {
    margin: 10
  }
}
```

You can also specify different margins for top, bottom, right, left like this:

```
const options = {
  nodes: {
    margin: {
      top: 10,
      bottom: 20,
      left: 5,
      right: 5
  }
}
```

I can't seem to specify in anything but px - i tried to use '1em' for input, but it seems it only takes integer values - and expresses it in pixels.

In case you're curious, i found the information i needed from the `options.js` file located in `node_modules\vis\lib\network`. If you're looking for options for the other areas of vis (like timeline), i bet there is an options file for that in a similar folder.

Comment: margin only works if image isn't set

Answer (score 1):

This property is not yet customizable, however I managed to change it directly in the `vis.js` source file:

- Search for the Box class definition : `var Box = function (_NodeBase)`
- In the resize function there is the margin to modify : `var margin = 5;`
- Change it to whatever you want, and it's done

Answer (score 0):

I've been just hitting the same problem. The only solution I found was to set `borderWidth` and `borderWidthSelected` of the node to the amount of padding I wanted. To make it not look too ugly, you can also set the border the same color as the background of the node.

Besides, it gives the graph a nice modern flat look.

Comment: Indeed, I've used this same workaround. It does have several drawbacks - for instance, you can no longer have a border on the nodes, because your border is now effectively part of the background. Also, this means you can no longer use semi-transparent nodes - that is, use an `rgba()` colour for node background, with `alpha < 1`. That is because if you use the same semi-transparent colour on the border, the border and the background will overlap (border is drawn centered), and you'll end up with an unwanted 'inner border'...